# How to remove SearchView remove Icon

Tags: android, xml, searchview

[This is the EDIT image: it shows the space i want to remove;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcgwG.png) I am making a search for my app. I just can't seem to remove the "SearchView" icon.

HERE'S THE XML:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#e9eaea"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:padding="0dp"
tools:context="com.echo.isaac.echo_simplyawesome.Search">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop">

            <SearchView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:queryHint="@string/search"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:paddingLeft="-16dp"
                android:paddingStart="-16dp"
                android:theme="@style/SearchViewStyle"
                android:background="@drawable/input_background_teal"
                android:queryBackground="@drawable/input_background_teal"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop_mr1" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

     </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I just want to remove the icon next to the SearchView text box. So I dont have a big empty space next to it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override search view default image or set visible gone

```
int searchImgId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
ImageView searchImage = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchImgId);


searchImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: I was able to set visibility to gone but that still made the spacing the same

Comment: searchImage is null for me